# How to put 19 digit or more digit number in a excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to put 19 digit or more digit number in a excel cell.

I want to save 19 digit number in cell of column .How I will format that cell.Can anybody give me some idea in this regard?

Comment: Huh? Is it not letting you?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve? What application requires a 19 digit number?

Comment: you just want to display the number or do you want to do maths with it?

Answer (score 6):

You can always store the number in the cell as a string. Put an apostrophe in front of the number.

Comment: What if I already added ' before the bumbers (from database). How to hide ' before each entry now? (I'm not inputting numbers manually)

Answer (score 5):

If you change the format of the cell to 'Text', you don't need to prepend an apostrophe; you just put in the number.  It will still even be usable as a number by functions that refer to the cell.

Answer (score 5):

When you don't need to calculate with these numbers, you can treat them as text, see the other answers. When you need to calculate with them, then it becomes difficult because Excel has only 15 siginificant digits. The possibilities I know are:

1. Split the number in 2 (or more) cells. Put a part of the number in one cell and the remainder in another cell. The consequence is that you need to develop your own formules for calculations.
2. Another solution is using add-in's. For a free one study the articles mentioned in http://www.excel-ticker.com/calculation-of-very-large-numbers-in-excel-part-5-add-in/

Answer (score 2):

Excel seems to allow only 15 digits. What on Earth are you doing that really requires 19 digits of precision? I suspect you're either not stating your problem well or you're worry about unnecessary details.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to copy / type in excel with more than 15 numbers. Pls follow the steps given below:

1. If you want to type a number which is more than 15 digits, simply select that particular column, go to format cells, and select "text". After that, whatever numbers you type it will give you in text format.
2. If you want to copy a number which has more than 15 digits, simply, first copy and paste that particular number/rows/columns into notepad, again copy the content from notepad, go to excel select full sheet and right click to select format type as "text", and now past the copied content in the excel. It automatically shows you all the digits without any rounded off.

Answer (score 0):

Cause Excel only works with numerics up to 15 digits you have to separate the number and after `concatenate`

example:

```
A2                  B2      C2
894450360114541404  10000   894450360114551404

=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,10),NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,8))+B2)
```

Comment: the A2 is a number of 18Digits